# Checking MacTeX version installed on a Mac

Tags: mactex

I can use `latex -v` to check the version of LaTeX. Is there a way to check what version of MacTeX (MacTeX 2008, 2009 or 2010) is installed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

MacTeX installs a System Preferences pane which shows TeX installations for selection. There you can see the version.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Oh. I thought he wanted something that he could check programmatically.

Comment: This is the right (i.e., Mac-like) answer.  I totally forgot about the preference pane.

Comment: If I am correct, this is no longer the case with TexLive 2016 on Mac OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: This is no longer the case, indeed. Look for the TeX Live Utility app instead.

Answer (score 9):

The latest info as of May 2019.

`Tex Live Utility` allows you to check the MacTex version you are currently using (and to switch to other version if needed). There is no longer a `System Preferences` pane for this purpose.

[The MacTex website](https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html) says:

> Long ago we installed a Preference Pane which could do this switching,
>   but this functionality is now in TeX Live Utility, which is in
>   /Applications/TeX. To switch, use the Configure menu item "Select
>   Default TeX Live Version."

Answer (score 5):

```
; readlink /usr/texbin
../usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-darwin
```

Comment: Weird. On my mac that gives `../Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/i386`  But `readlink /usr/textbin/` (note the trailing slash) gives `../../../../../../../usr/local/texlive/2010/bin/x86_64-darwin`

Comment: Yeah, `/Library/TeX/Distributions/` contains a whole mess of links. I have no idea why my `/usr/texbin` is a direct link rather than indirecting though said mess.

Comment: Your programmatical approach is fine. I like the command line.

Answer (score 5):

Found [this answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/492743/549531) which essentially says:

- Run `pdflatex --version`
- The first row contains the version `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)` (2020 in my case)

Answer (score 4):

In 2010, this worked:

```
cd /usr/texbin && pwd -P
```

and gave something like `/usr/local/texlive/2009/bin/universal-darwin`.

For more recent versions, use

```
cd /Library/TeX/Root && pwd -P
```

which gives something like `/usr/local/texlive/2018`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a "hello world" latex file and compile it.  Look at the console or `.log` file and see what files are being loaded.  On my machine I see

`(/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls...`

So you can guess it's TL 2010.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```sh
which tex # shows which and where your MacTex is installed
```

Or:

```sh
tex --version # or `tex -v`
```